# marmap producing large white margins

Tags: r

I've been trying to use the R library marmap to produce a bathymetric plot, but no matter what I do I end up getting large white areas either side of the actual map. Even just cutting and pasting the code examples from the marmap manual produces the same white regions and does not reproduce the figures in the manual itself. I've tried the solutions suggested in

[How to reduce the space between the plot and the border for geographic maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52935943/how-to-reduce-the-space-between-the-plot-and-the-border-for-geographic-maps)

but the first suggestion by Benoit produces a highly distorted image, and the second solution still ends up producing the white regions to the left and right of the actual map. According to Benoit, the white regions result from setting the aspect ratio of the map, but there seems to be no way to set the lat and long limits on the plot without setting `asp=NA` (his first solution) which produces a highly distorted map in my case. A MWE (without the attempted solutions) is

```
library("marmap")
arabian_sea <- getNOAA.bathy(lon1 = 55, lon2 = 75, lat1 = 0, lat2 = 30, resolution=5, keep=TRUE)
blues <- c("lightsteelblue4", "lightsteelblue3", "lightsteelblue2", "lightsteelblue1")
p_map0 <- plot(arabian_sea, image = TRUE, land = TRUE, lwd = 0.1, 
     bpal = list(c(0, max(arabian_sea), "grey"),
                 c(min(arabian_sea),0,blues)))
```

which produces the following map

[Arabian Sea map produced by marmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpFLI.jpg)

So whereas the bathymetry in `arabian_sea` goes from 55 to 75 degrees, the image goes from something like 40 to 90 degrees leaving large white bands to the left and right of the actual bathymetric plot. I've also tried using `xlim` and `ylim` to manually set the window properties, but that had no effect either. I'm obviously missing something fundamental here somewhere, but I can't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried manually reducing the size of the plotting window?

[image]

You can also manually set the size of the plotting device from within your script:

```
png(width = 780, height = 1169)
plot(arabian_sea, image = TRUE, land = TRUE, lwd = 0.3, 
  bpal = list(c(0, max(arabian_sea), "grey"),
              c(min(arabian_sea),0,blues)))
dev.off()
```

Which produces the following file (Rplot001.png by default) within your working directory:

[image]

This is kind of a guessing game though. If you still have white margins on the left and right sides of the plot, either decrease the `width` value of the `png()` call, or increase the `height` value. If, on the contrary, you have white margins on top and bottom of your graph, then increase `width` or decrease `height`. Again, this is due to the fixed `asp` of maps. If you don't want your map to look distorted, you have to leave `asp = 1`. But then, all you can do to remove unwanted white areas around your plot, is to fiddle with the size/shape of the plotting region itself.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, Benoit, that worked. Sometimes it's the simplest things that get you.